# json_decode url instagram return Null with PHP code

Tags: php, json, url, instagram

i have a question from json_decode url instagram https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1 return Null with php

```
        $newwul = "http://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1";
        $xo =  connect($newwul);
        $xx = json_decode($xo,true);
        $endcount = $xx['logging_page_id'];
        $userid = $xx['graphql']['user']['id'];
        var_dump($xo);//return NULL
        var_dump($xx);//return NULL
```

they is my function connect

```
function connect($urlx){
    $cookie_file_path = "cookies/c.txt";
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36";

    $urlex = ($urlx);
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlex);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'cookie:ig_cb=1; rur=PRN; mid=XV_v7gAEAAFbvgXMUd0PClkTvnla; csrftoken=fs1r3L5SxkJvrN6g2w239nhMgppQGVLc; urlgen="{\"185.56.80.156\": 43350}:1i2zL0:8TaH7yECjymjQH80LduQiFUJZE0"',
   ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $urlex);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,100);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    return $req = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

any solution please?

Comment: Because your connect function were return null value. Probably, you could not connect to instagram with your curl. Please recheck error of curl with :https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Au Nguyen thank you for your answer
I still have the same problem without function connect()
I think there is a problem in the link
For Example It's ok for this url ```
$newwul = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452"; $xo = connect($newwul); $xx = json_decode($xo,true); $endcount = $xx['status']; echo $endcount; //REQUEST_DENIED
```

Comment: Au Nguyen thank you for your answer I still have the same problem without function connect() I think there is a problem in the link For Example It's ok for this url [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452)

Comment: I guess that you have hit the Instagrams request rate limit and the response is `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Please view example for curl instagram:

```
<?php
$newwul = "http://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $newwul);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data_curl = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($data_curl);
?>
```